# Proving that, a particular binary operation is the only possible operation.

Tags: functions, binary-operations

I attempted the following question:

**Show that the number of binary operations on {1,2} having 1 as identity and having 2 as the inverse of 2 is exactly one.**

My approach to solve the problem was this:

The question gives a suggestion about a particular operation.
For that operation,  the identity is ‘1’.
Also, for that operation, the inverse of 2 is ‘2’.

I was able to understand that, the suggested operation will give the results for all the possible combinations (1,1), (1,2), (2,1) and (2,2).
But I am not able to prove that it is **the only possible operation**.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is the binary operations that satisfy those properties.

We already know that $f(1,x)=x$ and $f(x,1)=x$ for all $x \in \{1,2\}$ since $1$ is the identity.

$f(1,1)=1, f(1,2)=2, f(2,1)=2$.

$f(2,2)=1$ since $2$ is the inverse of $2$, since everything has been fully specified it must be unique.

---

Suppose not, then we can find $f$ and $g$ both being binary operations that satisfy those properties and some $x, y\in\{1,2\}$ such that $f(x,y) \ne g(x,y)$.

However, we can enumerate all $x$ and $y$ and check that such $x$ and $y$ do not exist. Hence it is a contradiction.

---

In general, if something has been fully specified, it is unique.